# Associated type family complains about `pred :: T a -> Bool` with "NB: ‘T’ is a type function, and may not be injective"

Tags: haskell, types, type-families

This code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Study where

class C a where
    type T a :: *
    pred :: T a -> Bool
```

— Gives this error:

```
.../Study.hs:7:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘T a’ with ‘T a0’
      Expected type: T a -> Bool
        Actual type: T a0 -> Bool
      NB: ‘T’ is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘Study.pred’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method:
        Study.pred :: forall a. A a => T a -> Bool
      In the class declaration for ‘A’
  |
7 |     pred :: T a -> Bool
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Replacing `type` keyword with `data` fixes.

- Why is one wrong and the other correct?
- What do they mean by "may not be injective"? What kind of function that is if it is not even allowed to be one to one? And how is this related to the type of `pred`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
instance C Int where
  type T Int = ()
  pred () = False

instance C Char where
  type T Char = ()
  pred () = True
```

So now you have two definitions of `pred`. Because a type family assigns just, well, type synonyms, these two definitions have the signatures

```
pred :: () -> Bool
```

and

```
pred :: () -> Bool
```

Hm, looks rather similar, doesn't it? The type checker has no way to tell them apart. What, then, is

```
pred ()
```

supposed to be? `True` or `False`?

To resolve this, you need some explicit way of providing the information of which instance the particular `pred` in some use case is supposed to belong to. One way to do that, as you've discovered yourself, is to change to an associated `data` family: `data T Int = TInt` and `data T Char = TChar` would be two distinguishable new types, rather than synonyms to types, which have no way to ensure they're actually different. I.e. data families are always injective; type families sometimes aren't. The compiler assumes, in the absence of other hints, that *no* type family is injective.

You can declare a type family injective with another language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
class C a where
  type T a = (r :: *) | r -> a
  pred :: T a -> a
```

The `=` simply binds the `r`esult of `T` to a name so it is in scope for the injectivity annotation, `r -> a`, which reads like a functional dependency: the `r`esult of `T` is enough to determine the `a`rgument. The above instances are now illegal; `type T Int = ()` and `type T Char = ()` together violate injectivity. Just one by itself is admissible.

Alternatively, you can follow the compiler's hint; `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes` makes the original code compile. However, you will then need `-XTypeApplications` to resolve the instance at the use site:

```
pred @Int () == False
pred @Char () == True
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add a "theory" part to your post that answers the second point in my question, even if sketchily.

Comment: I already gave an example to that. My instances have made the `T` type family non-injective, because the make `T Int ~ T Char ~ ()`.

Comment: Oh. I see. I read the Nota Bene in the error message as "... (may not) (be injective) *(never ever)*" while it should be read as "... (may) (not be injective) *(sometimes)*". So, what it says is that the type function, when it is variously instantiated, may happen to not be one to one anymore and, therefore, certain class of type signatures would become ambiguous. May I ask you to put an explanation along these lines somewhere in your answer for the sake of the future reader?

Comment: @HTNW I cannot compile your example with `TypeFamilyDependencies`. It says `parse error on input ‘::’`. Do I need to enable some other extensions?

Comment: ...If I omit the kind signature, like this: `type T a = r | r -> a`, — it compiles fine.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Whoops, I ate some parentheses.